# How can i catch a modal this.$emit using ionic modal controller

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, ionic-vue

Hello i'm converting somme of my web code to an ionic-vue app and i wanted to know if we can catch a this.$emit from my modal using the ionic modal controller insted of classic vuecomponent.

basically i want to translate

```
<NewAppointmentModal @onSuccess="handleAppointmentCreation"/>
```

to

```
this.$ionic.modalController.create({ component: NewAppointmentModal}).then(m => m.present())
//how can i catch the onSuccess event like before
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ParentComponent.vue

```
public openModal() {
    return this.$ionic.modalController
    .create({
      component: ModalComponent,
      componentProps: {
        data: {
          content: 'New Content',
        },
        propsData: {
          //user_id: user_id
        },
        parent: this,
      },
    })
    .then(m => m.present({

    }))
}

public mounted() {
   this.$on('close', (foo) => {
       this.$ionic.modalController.dismiss()
   })
}
```

ModalComponent.vue

```
<template>
   <ion-button @click="dismissModal()">Close</ion-button>
</template>
<script>
   dismissModal() {
     this.$parent.$emit('close', { foo: 'bar' })
   }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

> Brian answered correct, but there are a code line change in Vue 3:     ParentComponent.vue

```
 this.$on('close', () => {
       this.$ionic.modalController.dismiss()
   })
```

Comment: Do you know a solution to what I can use instead "this.$on" since it is deprecated?