# Catch emits with ionic modal controller

Tags: vue.js, ionic-framework, vuejs3

How can I catch the this.$emit from the ionic model controller?
I've found this question, but the solution is deprecated:
[How can i catch a modal this.$emit using ionic modal controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57098308/how-can-i-catch-a-modal-this-emit-using-ionic-modal-controller#comment119342538_67382475)
How should I do this in Vue3?

My code looks like this:

```
mounted() {
    this.$on('updateMaterialList', () => {
        this.$ionic.modalController.dismiss()
    })
  }
```

The error is the following:

```
The Events api `$on`, `$off` `$once` is deprecated.
```

Comment: Hi, Have a look on this migration doc https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/migration/events-api.html#overview

Comment: can you provide more code on what you are trying to accomplish with the modal?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this recently by passing a prop "update" with the function "updateProducts" and defining the prop "update" in the modal component and then calling it with a this.update(product). This would update the modal without closing it.

```
this.modal = await modalController.create({
                component: ProductUpdateModal,
                componentProps: {
                  title: 'Update Product',
                  update: (product) => this.updateProducts(product)
              },
                
            })
```

In modal component:

```
props: {
  title: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Product'
  },
  update: { type: Function }
},


methods: {
   updateProductInfo(product) {
      this.update(product);         
   },
}
```